# How to remove a subfolder with unknown folder name?

Tags: batch-file, rmdir

I have a folder **D:\test1** and I have another folder inside that whose name is not known.

I tried using `rmdir /s "D:\test\*"`, but it is showing an error.

I just want to know is there any way of doing this operation?

In shell script if we give `rmdir "D:\test1\*"` it will remove all directories inside **test1**.

I am looking for the command in batch syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest

```
@echo off
for /D %%F in ("D:\test1\*") do rmdir /S /Q "%%F"
```

It deletes all subfolders in `D:\test1` recursively even if subfolders contain one or more spaces in folder name.